# Percent symbol not getting evaluated in makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm new to makefiles etc.

The file looks like this:

```
COMPILER_NAME = gcc
COMPILER_FLAGS =

PATH_OBJECTS = ./obj
PATH_SOURCES = ./src

$(PATH_OBJECTS)/%.o: $(PATH_SOURCES)/%.c
    $(info Generating object files...)
    @$(COMPILER_NAME) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@

cleanup: $(PATH_OBJECTS)/%.o
    $(info Final cleanup...)
    @rm -rf $<
```

When i try to actually make the project i get this error:
    make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/%.o', needed by 'cleanup'.  Stop.

It's like the % wildcard is not getting evaluated correctly. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pattern  rule has '%' in the *target*, and maybe in one or more of the prerequisites. What you have:

```
cleanup: $(PATH_OBJECTS)/%.o
    ...
```

is not a pattern rule, and that '%' is not a wildcard, it's just a character. That's an ordinary rule that looks for a file called **"./obj/%"** as a prerequisite, and there's no such file.

If you want `cleanup` to remove all of the object files in that directory, there's no need for any of this complication. Just do this:

```
cleanup:
    @echo Final cleanup...
    @rm -rf $(PATH_OBJECTS)/*.o
```

Note that this uses the shell command `echo`, not the Make command `info`, and the shell wildcard '*', not the Make wildcard '%'.

If you want a target to depend on all the object files you can build, you must construct that list yourself; it's not difficult, but it doesn't look like something you need here.

Comment: Even the first target doesn't work. My folder structure is as follows:

root
---- bin
---- obj
---- src
-------- main.c

But the c file does not get compiled nor it gets moved to ./obj

Also, if I try to remove the cleanup target, i get this error

"make: *** No targets.  Stop."

Even though the target is there.

Comment: @FedericoLuzzi: You misunderstand what a pattern rule does. Try `make ./obj/main.o`.

Comment: The key understanding is that a pattern rule doesn't say "find all files that can be built matching this pattern and build them".  A pattern rule is a _template_; it says "if you're trying to build a target, and it matches this pattern rule, then you can use this recipe to build it".  You still have to, separately and explicitly, somehow tell make which targets you want to build.